# Port 22 is open by default in public cluster GKE

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

This page says that port 22 is open for public clusters in GKE:

"For public clusters only. Permits the control plane to access the Kubelet and metrics-server on cluster nodes."

https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/firewall-rules

I was wondering is this only used for troubleshooting and metrics or if I remove that firewall rule the cluster will stop working?

Thank you!

Comment: Your link has the message: `Warning: Do not modify or delete firewall rules created by GKE, or you might encounter unexpected behavior in your clusters.`

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to stackoverflow..,

SSH firewall rule not required for the correct functioning of the cluster. If that firewall rule is removed then the kubectl logs, attach, exec, and port-forward commands stop responding.

For more information refer the [link](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/troubleshooting#kubect_commands_stops)

In this [stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49554267/no-ssh-tunnels-currently-open-were-the-targets-able-to-accept-an-ssh-key-for-us) you can clearly find what type of errors will occur if that firewall rule has been removed.

But don't delete as suggested by John Hanley.